# Как копировать текст в input value в буфер обмена при нажатии на иконку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, как в из `input` копировать значение `value` в **буфер обмена** при нажатии на иконку?

```
<div class="form-group form-group__ico">
   <label for="card-num">2. Номер банковской карты получателя</label>
   <input name="card_num" type="text" class="form-control" id="card-num" required value="2200280421677347">
   <img class="image-copy" src="img/form-ico.svg" title="Скопировать" alt="Icon">
</div>

$(function() {
  $('.image-copy').click(function() {
     $('#card-num')[0].select(); 
     document.execCommand('copy');
     $('#card-num').append(' ');
     $('#card-num').val().slice(0, -1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Скопировать куда и откуда?

Comment: В буфер обмена https://prnt.sc/pcgkXoOqJiZJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Копирование содержимого input в буфер обмена

```
  document.querySelector('.image-copy').addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementById('card-num').value);
  })
```

Comment: Следует учитывать, что приём работает [только в защищенных контекстах](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard)

Comment: Спасибо! Работает