# Скопировать ссылку изображения при клике

Tags: javascript

Можно ли одним кликом скопировать ссылку на изображение?

```
Nsm=86; //Всего смайликов 
pat='/FbBigSmiles/'; 
for(i=1; i<=Nsm; i++) { 
    kod='[img]'+pat+i+'.png[/img]'; 
    document.write('<a href="javascript://" onClick="emoticon('); 
    document.write("'"+kod+"'"); 
    document.write(');return false;"><img border="0" src="'+pat+i+'.png"></a> '); 
}
```

Comment: [Скопировать в буфер обмена текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496677/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-input-value-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83/1496683#1496683)

Answer (score 0):

```
const pat = '/FbBigSmiles/';
const Nsm = 86;

for (let i = 1; i <= Nsm; i++) {
  const kod = '[img]' + pat + i + '.png[/img]';
  const link = `https://example.com/messages/${i}`;
  const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
  linkElement.href = link;
  linkElement.textContent = 'Copy link';
  linkElement.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const dummy = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = link;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
  });
  document.write('<a href="javascript://" onClick="emoticon(');
  document.write("'" + kod + "'");
  document.write(');return false;"><img border="0" src="' + pat + i + '.png"></a> ');
  document.body.appendChild(linkElement);
}
```